# Laravel 4 - How to set input value as a route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to implement a text input field via Blade to my view in Laravel 4.

```
{{ Form::open(array("route" => "search.show")) }}
    {{ Form::text("name") }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The text input posts a string to my controller, that is used to select some data from my database via

```
class SearchController extends \BaseController {
    public function show($name) {
        return(Item::where("name", "like", "%" . $name . "%")->get());
    }
}
```

When I submit the form with the text input, I want to hit the `search.show` Route, that I implemented with

```
Route::resource("search", "SearchController");
```

Now I want to know, how to post the text to my `routes.php`, that my controller is able to get the input by the parameter of the `show` method?

I know I could enter the data via `Input::get("name")`, but isn't it a design failure, when `Router::resource` gives me the template for this?

Sorry for my bad english, but I hope you guys could help me out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specific need isn't answered by the Resource controller layout. A search in general will have a number of different facets beyond a keyword, although this isn't always true.

The best approach I can offer you would be to avoid using any of the pre-existing Resource Controller routes as you may need them for what they are actually for in the future.

You can add a search method to your Resource controller when you declare the routes.

```
Route::get('search', [
    'uses' => 'SearchController@search',
    'as' => 'search'
]);

Route::resource('SearchController');
```

However, as a resource controller is not a good solution for this. Use a regular controller. Just remove the resource controller call in routes.php and only implement the search method.

```
public function search()
{
    // Your code here
}
```

The advantages to this are that you take back full control over the naming of the route, the HTTP verb used (GET makes more sense for a search) and you don't pollute a resource controllers templated routes with functionality that doesn't belong.

The second part is how to pass variables. Searching is typically difficult using parameters passed in as separated arguments in the url. Using a GET request just use a query string.

```
http://myapp.com/search?keyword=search%20%keyword
```

Now just use the Input facade or dependency inject the Request class into the controller.

```
$keyword = Input::get('keyword');
```

Comment: That looks very helpful, I'll implement my needs like this, I guess. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a Request object to show method of the controller.

```
class SearchController extends \BaseController {
    public function show(Request $request) {
        $name = $request->input("name");
    }
}
```

Or you can do form model binding : http://scotch.io/quick-tips/php-tips/laravel-php/laravel-form-model-binding.

On Laravel 4.x you have to use the Input Facade

```
class SearchController extends \BaseController {
        public function show(Request $request) {
            $name = Input::get("name");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is Laravel 5... that the OP 'probably' isn't using.

Comment: Ah, but it's nice to know. An update to Laravel 5 should be possible, but I better check that before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's still in active development, so please don't use it unless you're testing it ;-)

Comment: @DavidBarker to be honest I don't have experience in Laravel 4

Answer (score 0):

if you using form better not using function which hash variable like `show($id)` function,  because url should be like this `.../search/show/{$id}`,  try use `store()` function.

```
public function store()
{
    $name = Input::get("name");
    /* your code */
}
```

==

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => "search.store")) }}
    {{ Form::text("name") }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: So you break the RESTful approach to suite your needs... square peg, round hole.